# Haskell - Pattern matches overlap?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Why do the pattern matches overlap in this code:

```
(+) (Roman (_, [])) x = x
(+) x (Roman (_, [])) = x
```

It would make sense considering `x + y` is the same as `y + x` but I don't think haskell takes care of that, or does it?

Comment: I get the feeling you should be using Monoid or smth.

Comment: What is the definition of `Roman`?

Answer (score 3):

`x` could be anything, so it could be `Roman (_,[])`.

Comment: how would I implement this without overlapping patterns then? basically, If one argument has an empty list in the second part of the tuple, I just want to return the other argument

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `x` matches anything.

You can use at-patterns to make them unique:

```
(+) (Roman (_, [])) x@(Roman(_, _:_) = x
(+) x@(Roman(_, _:_) (Roman (_, [])) = x
```